# Matplotlib cmap only showing grey

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I'm plot with matplotlib on python using 'tab20' color map with the following code:

```
colors=[str(float(year-1980)/(2017-1980)) for i in years];
fig,ax = plt.subplots()         
ax.scatter(Topic[:,0],Topic[:,1],c=colors,cmap='tab20')
```

but the plot I get is completely grey. What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By passing a list of strings to `c` in your `ax.scatter` call, you're telling matplotlib to treat them as color format strings. Since the strings look like they represent floats, it treats them as grayscale values. If you pass a list of floats instead, it should use the colormap correctly:

`colors = [float((year-1980)/(2017-1980)) for year in years]`

See [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) for more details, in particular:

> `cmap` : Colormap, optional, default: None
>
> A `Colormap` instance or registered name. `cmap` is only used if `c` is an
>   array of floats.

(Also, you don't need the `;` after your first line.)

Comment: This answer is definitely correct. But the questioner obviously did not understand it. Maybe you can simply add the code needed to solve the issue, namely `colors=[float(i-1980)/(2017-1980) for i in years]`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Good call, I've made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using 
    colors=[cm.RdYlBu(float(year-1980)/(2017-1980)) for i in years];
because I need to convert the float number to the colormap I wanted to use.

Comment: This is an option, but circumvents the initial problem by supplying the colors directly instead of letting the scatter choose the colors according to the colormap.

Comment: That is true. Any ideas that can directly sole the initial question? Would greatly appreciate it!